# Redirect to login page after logout in angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

In my Angular app, I redirect the user from home to the login page after logout. It works for a few seconds then Angular redirects to the home page again.

// routing paths

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([
        {path:"", component: HomeComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
        {path:"login", component: LoginComponent},
        {path:"signup", component: SignupComponent},
])
```

// AuthService.service.ts

```js
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  loggedUser!: any;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AngularFireAuth,
    private fireStore: AngularFirestore
  ) {}

 get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedUser !== null;
  }
   
 // logout function 
    async signout() {
       await this.auth.signOut();
       localStorage.removeItem('user');
       this.loggedUser = null; 
       this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
}
```

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router : Router){

    }
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        if(!this.authService.isLoggedIn){
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
        return true;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: can you check if there is subscription in app component which track the logout?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **pathMatch: 'full'** to you empty path

```
 {path:"", component: HomeComponent , pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
```

Comment: Hello Fateh, I have tried what you suggested, but still, it behaves the same.

Comment: can you add your authguard code to your question

Comment: Not quite sure if this would help but don't have you to put a slash before 'login' like this: this.router.navigate(['/login']);